# Stored Procedure for copying data from one table to another

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have **pairs of tables** in the format `TABLE` and `TABLE_TWIN` now

- `TABLE` is the main table with lots of data
- `TABLE_TWIN` is a table with the exact same fields with a little data (different data)

Now I would like to copy all rows from `TABLE_TWIN` to `TABLE` using a stored procedure. I have many such tables and could like the stored procedure to take the table name(s) as parameter(s) so that I can use the same procedure for each table pair. I do not want to write **long `INSERT`** statements because these tables have around 50 attributes each.

I am not good with PL/SQL so I need some help here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL is not so long... But if you prefer a procedure, here it is:

```
create or replace procedure table_copy(
  p_tab_from varchar2,
  p_tab_to   varchar2)
is
begin
  execute immediate 'insert into '||p_tab_to||' (select * from '||p_tab_from||')';
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
insert into table_twin (select * from table)
```

should do it