# How to move/copy data from one table to another using stored procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have pairs of tables `tbl` and `tbl_backup`

Now 'tbl' is the main table with lots of data
'tbl_backup' is a table with the exact same fields
Now I would like to copy all rows from 'tbl' to 'tbl_backup' using a stored procedure. I'd like to do the same with many such tables and hence I'd like to use the stored procedure.

I am not good with PL/SQL so I need some help here.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need to backup those tables use data pump export utility(`expdp`). Based on the information you've provided I see no reason to implement Backup and Recover strategy that way, especially using PL/SQL. Use appropriate tools: `expdp/impdp`, `rman`. If you need to restore data relatively quickly increase value of the `undo_retention` parameter and make use of `flashback query`.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure backup_table
    ( i_source_table in varchar2
    , i_target_table in varchar2 )
    authid current_user
is
begin
    execute immediate '
        insert --+ append
            into '||sys.dbms_assert.enquote_name(sys.dbms_assert.sql_object_name(i_target_table))||'
        select *
        from '||sys.dbms_assert.enquote_name(sys.dbms_assert.sql_object_name(i_source_table))
    ;
end;
```

Comment: Seen one more answer for this problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842672/stored-procedure-for-copying-data-from-one-table-to-another?answertab=votes#tab-top