# Oracle insert data from another table without column names

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables. They differ only columns order.

First

```
Table1
(
name,
surname,
age
)
```

Second

```
Table2
(
age
surname,
name
)
```

I want insert data to Table2 from Table1.

If tables column order is the same I can use

```
insert into Table2
select * from Table1
```

I know that I can solve this problem with

```
insert into table2
select age,surname,name from table1
```

But I don't use it because there are many column in my real table.

is there good idea for it?

Comment: you have to list the columns

Comment: @Aleksej is there not another way?

Comment: not with plain sql; you would need dynamic sql, that is a pl/sql block

Comment: well if you cannot manually do this ( you can copy all the columns with commas and put them in insert using toad or sqlplus, or selecting from user_tab_cols ) or with plsql block statment looping

Comment: @ArockiaRajV the link you post is relate to sql server, he is using oracle

Comment: @Aleksej I wrote with columns names. But I want to know how to solve this problem. Do you write pl/sql code as awnser?

Comment: for pl/sql you can create one as explained here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842672/stored-procedure-for-copying-data-from-one-table-to-another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way is with some dynamic SQL, by relying on column names; for example, say you have the tables

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    name                                    VARCHAR2(100),
    surname                                 VARCHAR2(100),
    age                                     NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
    name                                    VARCHAR2(100),
    age                                     NUMBER,
    oneMoreColumn                           NUMBER,
    surname                                 VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

you can do:

```
declare
    vSQL    varchar2(1000);
    vCols   varchar2(1000);
begin    
    select listagg(tc1.column_name, ', ') within group (order by tc1.column_name)
    into vCols
    from user_tab_columns tc1
           inner join user_tab_columns tc2
             on(tc1.column_name = tc2.column_name)
    where tc1.table_name = 'TABLE1'
      and tc2.table_name = 'TABLE2';
    --
    vSQL := 'insert into table2( ' || vCols || ') select ' || vCols || ' from table1';
    --
    dbms_output.put_line(vSQL);
    --
    execute immediate vSQL;
end;
```

this will build and execute the statement:

```
insert into table2( AGE, NAME, SURNAME) select AGE, NAME, SURNAME from table1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
create table EX_EMPLOYEE
(
  NAME VARCHAR2(100),
  PATH VARCHAR2(1000)
)


SET serveroutput ON size 2000
/
declare T_COL varchar2(50);
   CURSOR c1 IS SELECT column_name name FROM user_tab_cols where table_name='EX_EMPLOYEE';
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
    if T_COL is null then
    T_COL := T_COL || rec.name;
    else
    T_COL := T_COL ||' ,' || rec.name;
        end if;

  END LOOP;
      dbms_output.put_line('select '|| T_COL ||' FROM EX_EMPLOYEE');
END;
/



select NAME ,PATH FROM EX_EMPLOYEE

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

create table new_table as
select * from old_table